# Why does Jet's old watch show 15 hours?

Tags: cowboy-bebop

In Session #10 of *Cowboy Bebop*, "Ganymede Elegy", we see Jet's old Ganymede watch. Its face is divided in 15 intervals, instead of the usual 12 hours.

[image: A watch showing the numbers 1–15 on its face]

What are those 15 intervals supposed to measure?

---

*Ganymede is in tidal lock with Jupiter. It shows its same side to Jupiter at all times. [I've asked over on the Astronomy Stack](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/q/21660/16292) what its effect on the day/night cycle of Ganymede is. It's [current (self-)answer](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/a/21674/16292) says that there is no likely cycle of 15 or 30 intervals in Ganymede's orbit or rotation. The tidal lock means that the mean solar day on Ganymede is Ganymede's sidereal day, set off a bit by Jupiter's orbit around the sun, clocking in at little over 7 earth days.*

Comment: The clear implication is that Ganymede has a 30 hour day.

Comment: Hush now, your logic and research have no place here.

Comment: Or, perhaps humanity has started using a 15 or 30-hour clock across the solar system, because it was judged more convenient (for *reasons*) as a "Solar System Standard Time" metric.  I don't recall the show ever bothering to explain how hours are kept in-universe, apart from showing this shot of his watch.

Comment: maybe noteworthy - there are only 12 inner markings and the position of the hands is not as it would be on a clock (the hour hand should have moved from the full hour).  The whole layout reminds me on the decimal time clock on [wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Decimal_time).

Comment: Ganymede may be tidally locked to Jupiter, but it still orbits around Jupiter. To an observer standing on Ganymede, the Sun will still be going up and down, even though Jupiter seems to never move. Time is based on solar movement; so being tidally locked to Jupiter has no bearing on how time systems are expected to work.

Comment: @SQB: There's no reason for Earth to have **24** hours instead of 136 or 9. This is a completely arbitrary number. We picked 24 because it has many different divisors (1,2,4,6,8,12) How long a solar day on Ganymede takes is not necessarily relevant to the amount of hours in a Ganymede day.

Comment: @SQB: "there is no likely cycle of 15 or 30 intervals in Ganymede's orbit or rotation" There is also no likely cycle of 24 or 12 intervals in an Earth solar day. No solar day anywhere has any objectively discernable intervals. We have created those ourselves, in the interest of keeping track of time. However many hours are in a day, it is an arbitrary number, chosen for practical mathematical reasons; not because it in some way expresses the precise length of the solar day.

Comment: @Flater that is true, but _Cowboy Bebop_ is set in the late 21st century and Ganymede has been colonised by humans. It's likely that humans have retained most if not all of the base units of measurement from earth. As [this speculative calendar for the Galilean moons](https://ops-alaska.com/time/gangale_jupiter/jupiter.htm) shows, there are good options for possible calendar systems that still use the earth hour.

Comment: @Flater of course, you're welcome to post an answer.

Comment: Perhaps its not a watch?

Comment: A Watanabe commentary (for the episode Ganymede Elegy?) that mentions the watch is referenced [here](https://www.reddit.com/r/anime/comments/5237k0/spoilersrewatch_cowboy_bebop_episode_10_ganymede/) - ***"Speaking of which, the watch is something Watanabe seems proud of for its 15-hour dial (one of many cutaway visual cues to the passage of time), which suggests terra-forming Ganymede somehow involved changing its rotations (as, in reality, it's tide-locked)."***

Comment: It’s not true that there are no discernible intervals for earth. One moon unit. Or one traversal around the sun. Our day could be 360 minutes. Noon would be 180.

Comment: @Flater "We picked 24 because it has many different divisors (1,2,4,6,8,12)" [ [citation needed](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Citation_needed) ].

Answer (score 2):

One Mathematical possibility, based on the fact Ganymede takes ~7.16 Earth Days to orbit Jupiter and thus for the sun to appear to circle the moon. (1 Ganymede solar day)

IF the Ganymede people decided to shorten their Ganymede Hour to be ~57.33 Earth minutes. It would take 180 Ganymede hours for a Ganymede solar day. OR 15 x 12.

Thus the inner ring of twelve marks would track the 12 "Ganymede hours" like on a normal watch. And the outer ring of "fifteen" would track the number 12 hours intervals that had passed.

So at Dawn it might read 0:0, and at Sunset it might read 7:6. (7 twelve hours intervals + six hours = 90 hours or half a solar day.)

So the picture above assuming the long hand points to the outer ring of numbers, would be 3:0 or 36 Ganymede hours into the current Ganymede solar day.

I have no info that this is what the correct answer is, BUT as I said it would work mathematically if the length of a Ganymede 60 minute hour was shortened to equal 57.33 earth minutes.